# fadeIn de divs num loop?

Tags: jquery, html

Eu tenho o seguinte código que gostava que fizesse `fadeIn` e `fadeOut` passados 3 segundos. Pensei em usar `setInterval` para fazer o loop e depois usar um `setTimeout` para dar o tempo que cada `div` estava visível. Existe alguma forma de fazer o que desejo? Tenho algo mal no meu código?

```
setInterval(function(){
    setTimeout(function(){
        $(".emer3").fadeOut("fast");
        $(".emer1").fadeIn("fast");
    }, 3000);

    setTimeout(function(){
        $(".emer1").fadeOut("fast");
        $(".emer2").fadeIn("fast");
    }, 3000);

    setTimeout(function(){
        $(".emer2").fadeOut("fast");
        $(".emer3").fadeIn("fast");
    }, 3000);
}, 9000);



<div class="col-lg-12 col-sm-12 col-xs-12 col-md-12" style="margin-top:100px;">
  <div class="col-lg-4 col-sm-4 col-xs-4 col-md-4 emer1">
    252 252 252
  </div>
  <div class="col-lg-4 col-sm-4 col-xs-4 col-md-4 emer2" style="display:none">
    252 252 252
  </div>
  <div class="col-lg-4 col-sm-4 col-xs-4 col-md-4 emer3" style="display:none">
    252 252 252
  </div>
</div>
```

Exemplo neste [JSFIDDLE](https://jsfiddle.net/nek7xugw/1/)

Comment: Mas qual é o problema com esse código ? Está funcionando, se não for esse o efeito, explica um pouco melhor, ficou meio confuso o que você quer fazer.

Comment: @AnthraxisBR https://jsfiddle.net/nek7xugw/1/ Veja aqui o exemplo

Comment: Qual é a ideia do `setInterval`? Queres voltar a esconder depois?

Comment: @Sergio O `setInterval` é suposto funcionar como um lopp infinito mas não está a resultar como esperado

Comment: Mas queres mostrar e depois esconder? O setTimeout corre 1 vez, e porque o queres correr de novo?

Comment: Porque são divs diferentes, cada uma com uma classe, e com esses setTimeout define o tempo que cada uma fica.

Comment: Voce quer fazer um pisca pisca?

Comment: @HudsonPH Não, quero que a div apareça, se mantenha por 3 segundos, desapareça e apareça a próxima

Comment: Os fades de jquery suportam *complete callbacks* para encadear animações. É isso que pretende fazer?

Comment: @Isac Não entendi bem o que disse

Comment: Estou a perguntar se a ideia era os 3 setTimeouts correrem um de cada vez em sequência? Ou se os 3 ao mesmo tempo?

Comment: @Isac Sequência

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No seu código o problema é que todos os `setTimeout` começam ao mesmo tempo, logo as esperas terminam simultâneo.

Quando quer encadear animações em Jquery deve utilizar a função de complete, que é um callback, desta maneira:

```
$(".umaclass").fadeIn("fast", function(){
    //aqui vem o código a executar quando esta animação acaba
});
```

Se não o fizer dessa forma então todos os fades para elementos diferentes correm em simultâneo.

Para o seu problema em concreto de animar divs em sequencia sugiro outra abordagem, que até é mais escalavel, construindo um array de divs a animar e animar em sequencia com base na posição em que vai.

Exemplo:

```js
const divs = [$(".emer1"), $(".emer2"),$(".emer3")]; //divs a animar
let i = 0; //div corrente

function animar(){
  divs[i].fadeOut("fast"); //fadeout do corrente
  i = (i+1>=divs.length)?0:i+1; //descobrir o proximo
  divs[i].fadeIn("fast", function(){ //fadein do proximo
    setTimeout(() => { animar() } ,3000); //esperar 3 segundos e repetir o processo
  });
}

setTimeout(()=>animar(), 3000); //iniciar tudo em 3 segundos
```

```css
.emer1 {
  background-color:cyan;
}

.emer2 {
  background-color:yellow;
}

.emer3 {
  background-color:green;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="col-lg-12 col-sm-12 col-xs-12 col-md-12" style="margin-top:100px;">
  <div class="col-lg-4 col-sm-4 col-xs-4 col-md-4 emer1">
    252 252 251
  </div>
  <div class="col-lg-4 col-sm-4 col-xs-4 col-md-4 emer2" style="display:none">
    252 252 252
  </div>
  <div class="col-lg-4 col-sm-4 col-xs-4 col-md-4 emer3" style="display:none">
    252 252 253
  </div>
</div>
```

Documentação do [`fadeIn`](http://api.jquery.com/fadein/) e do [`fadeOut`](http://api.jquery.com/fadeout/)

<sup>Nota: coloquei umas cores nos divs para que o efeito fosse mais evidente.</sup>

Comment: Muito Obrigado! Resultou na perfeição